# executing a program (euler_et) right from the folder but says file not found

Tags: ubuntu, sh

I have this executive euler_et called by another program but it says "sh: /home/software/euler2/euler_et: not found". I then tried to run euler_et directly and while I can see euler_et is right there I got error message "No such file or directory". Seems the Ubuntu system don't recognize that executive?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure the file is executable:

```
chmod 755 ./euler_et
```

Then run it like this:

```
./euler_et
```

If you continue to have 'No such file or directory' error messages, there is something wrong in the filename itself, or the path to it.

Comment: It is "-rwxr-xr-x". And when I use ./euler_et I got "-bash: ./euler_et: No such file or directory". What could be wrong with filename and path? I mean I am right inside that folder and the filename is correct...

Comment: I recompiled the problematic programs and seems solved the problem.

Comment: If it was such a pilot error I suggest to delete your question because it is likely not useful for anyone else.

Comment: Well there seems some intrinsic problem for EULER and this question might help its other users. I actually still had some issues and am waiting for the author to get back to me. I'll update when he replies my email.